# HTML5, geolocation in real time with marker

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, marker

I have this code:

```
function startTracking() {

   var trackId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(successCallback, null, {maximumAge:1000, timeout:60000, enableHighAccuracy:true});

    function successCallback(position){
        map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude));



            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position:  new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
                map: map,
                title: 'Posizione Attuale'

            });
            marker.setMap(map);  


    };

}
```

Now the app create a marker every time that I move. I would like that, on the map, I see only the marker where I'm in that moment, I won't see the marker on the previous position.

Comment: You could delete this marker and call your startTracking with setInterval()

Comment: If  I delete the marker, where I write the creation of the marker? after calling the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert a button for refresh and solve the problem..

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know the api but for instance :

```
function startTracking() {

 //Destroy the marker here

var trackId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(successCallback, null, {maximumAge:1000, timeout:60000, enableHighAccuracy:true});

function successCallback(position){
    map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude));



        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:  new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
            map: map,
            title: 'Posizione Attuale'

        });
        marker.setMap(map);  


};

}


setInterval(startTracking, 3000);
```

you may want to put the marker as global

Comment: I use this 'marker.setMap(null);' for destroy marker, but now I don't see anything

Comment: I don't know, I'm using a similar thing but with openlayers. The idea is to delete it and re-create it. You have to search about this.